# Troubles exporting raster to tiff in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, geotiff-tiff

I am exporting in ArcGIS a raster by doing Data > Export data. But in the Export Raster Data window, I don't have the option for choosing the file format.

Am I missing something? Perhaps must the Coordinate reference system of the raster be a projected one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With data > export data, you can define the output type by chosing your extension. Note that if your output workspace is a geodatabase, only raster dataset from geodatabase is possible:

> When you name your output raster dataset, specify .bmp for BMP, .gif
>   for GIF, .img for ERDAS IMAGINE, .jpg for JPEG, .jp2 for JPEG 2000,
>   .png for PNG, .tif for a TIFF file format, or no extension for a Grid
>   or a raster dataset in a geodatabase.

Answer (score 5):

The dialog for Data::Export Data contains the format:
[image]

It's been that way since at least version 9. This screen shot is from v10.1 and 10.2 is very similar (just a different drop down style).